# 1990s Hentai game involving characters based on traditional European fairy tales

Tags: story-identification, video-games, hentai

I played this in early high school, around 1994-1998, on a Windows PC, and recently, I keep having it pop up in my memories, so I'm hoping putting a name to it will put my brain to rest. The protagonist, male, winds up in a house with one or more fairy tale characters (or at least girls based off of them) living there. The game is in a 2D anime style. The only characters which stick in my head are one based off of Snow White (complete with a set of unwanted suitors in the forms of garden-gnome-sized dwarves), and a girl showing up in the backyard (I think as an optional encounter that you had to have certain actions/conditions to trigger) based off of Little Red Riding Hood. It's been so many years that I don't really remember any details, but I'm pretty sure it went as far as depicting cartoon sex with the girls, albeit with usual Japanese censorship.

I don't think the games had a large color palette. Part of me wants to say it was approaching the old 16 color model, maybe 256 at the most.

The gameplay, as I recall it, involved making various choices at the bottom of the screen, with the main graphics being in a window on the top. There was no combat involved, that I remembered. It was more like an adventure game, or possibly a visual novel.

Comment: What computer/console did you play it on? how many years ago did you originally play it?

Comment: Great... this has become an HNQ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another possibility is [Nocturnal Illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nocturnal_Illusion), a 1995 Japanese eroge that got an English release in 1998. The protagonist is trapped in a mysterious mansion after a fall in the mountains, and ends up meeting a number of women also trapped there. This includes two fairytale characters (the little mermaid and little red riding hood), though not Snow White. Gameplay is of the "look and think" variety of visual novel - you can examine and think about most items in a room.

[image]

Comment: I watched a gameplay video, and I think that's the one. The title sounds familiar too. Thank you. I can now wipe that one off of the slate of my head, hopefully.

Answer (score 7):

Most likely [Knights of Xentar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_of_Xentar), the 1995 English DOS release of Japanese game Dragon Knight III. As the wikipedia page says,

> Crude erotic humour is combined with classical fairy tales; the hero for examples save Little Red Riding Hood from rape by the Wolf, and Snow White from rape by the seven dwarves.

See if this battle scene looks familiar:

[image]

Comment: That's a good suggestion, and I had forgotten that that came also included fairy tale characters, but I don't remember combat factoring into it. Instead, I think it was a bit closer to either an adventure game, or a visual novel.